Get PDF content (from Outlook) to column in Excel Power Query
every month I am getting the report with invoices' numbers, amounts etc. I need to manually check if that invoice was sent to me via email and if so - is the amount on the invoice correct with what I have on a report.
So, here's example how my report looks like:



Date
Name
Amount
Invoice




05.06.2024
John Smith
3 EUR
123456


06.06.2024
John Black
9 EUR
654321



I got to the point where I import data from Microsoft Outlook Exchange and I have this table with all the emails etc. There's a column called Attachment which displays as Table.

When I click on this Table, I get to next view where I can see that AttachmentContent is binary.

I can also click further on this Binary and get into the next view where I see all tables within that PDF.

My question is - is it possible to extract following table (under) to new column so I can see that table for each file? Row/column etc, just how to extract that table out of binary form.

If I manually click into each binary file and tables, I can extract it to table only for that 1 specific item. I want to do it for for example 500 invoices at once.
Is it even possible through Excel? Maybe need some addons for reading binary content? I couldn't find anything in that matter that would help me.

Yes it is possible with Excel.Workbook(binary, true)
you can either use the UI and click the double arrows above the binary column (which I really don't like)
I personally use
Table.AddColumn(Source, "Table", each Excel.Workbook([binaryColumnName], true))

It doesn't create custom functions and sample files.
Careful that the 2nd approach ignores any standardization. The first one assumes they are all the same format files (based on the first file)
